# How do i convert String to currency?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, wsdl, asmx, currency

i am using 2 web services:

```
http://www.webservicex.com/currencyconvertor.asmx?WSDL

http://www.oorsprong.org/websamples.countryinfo/CountryInfoService.wso
```

One the second webservice i used ListOfCurrenciesByCode method and got the isoCode of currency and listed it in a dropdownlist1.DataTextField = "sISOCode"; and i get all the countries' ISOCODE.

Now i want to convert values using first link webservice using webmethod ConversionRate. How do i convert ?the ConversionRate method only seems to want me to input

```
 ConversionRate(Currency fromcurrency, Currency tocurrency).
```

How do i do that?

Answer (score 4):

```
String.Format("{0:C}", value);
```

Documentation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/AJAX_with_ASP_NET_MVC.aspx)

```
public string getConversionRate(string CurrencyFrom, string CurrencyTo)
{
   CurrencyConvertor curConvertor = new CurrencyConvertor();
   double rate = curConvertor.ConversionRate(
      (Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(Currency), CurrencyFrom),
      (Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(Currency), CurrencyTo));
   return rate.ToString();
}
```